# Applying Rouche's Theorem to $f_\epsilon(z) = f(z) + \epsilon g(z)$ on $\vert z \vert \leq 1$, where $f(0) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose f and $g$ are holomorphic in a region containing $|z|\leq 1$. Suppose that $f$ has simple zero at $z=0$, and vanishes nowhere else in $|z|\leq 1$. Let $f_\epsilon(z)=f(z)+\epsilon g(z)$.

> Show that
>
> 1. If $\epsilon$ is small, then $f_\epsilon(z)$ has unique zero in $|z|\leq 1$
> 2. If $z_\epsilon$ is this zero, then $\epsilon\mapsto z_\epsilon$ is continuous.

How to approach this problem? The uniqueness of the zero? Any hints and idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name $\gamma$ the unit circle.

For a) you have $$\vert f_\epsilon(z) - f(z) \vert =\epsilon \vert g(z) \vert \le \vert f(z) \vert$$ for $\epsilon < A  = \min\limits_{z \in \gamma} \left\vert\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right\vert$. $A$ exists because $g$ is supposed not to vanish on $\gamma$ and because $f$ and $g$ are continuous in the compact $\gamma$. $A >0$ because $f$ is continuous and not vanishing in $\gamma$.

By Rouché theorem, $f_\epsilon$ has the same number of zeros in the unit disk than $f$, i.e. one.

For b) use implicit function theorem applied to the function $F(z,\epsilon)=f(z)+\epsilon g(z)$. You probably need to suppose that $g$ is not vanishing in the closed unit disk.

Comment: Why isn't $g$ supposed to not vanish on $\gamma$?