# Question using Rouché's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from Stein Complex Analysis textbook page 106

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a region containing the disc
> $|z|\leq1$. Suppose that $f$ has a simple zero at $z=0$ and vanishes
> nowhere else in $|z|\leq 1$. Let $f_\epsilon(z)=f(z)+\epsilon g(z)$.
> Show that if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then $f_\epsilon (z)$
> has a unique zero in $|z|\leq 1$.

My approach:

Note that $|f(z)|>0$ if $z\in B_1(0)$ since $f(z)$ does not vanish on the circle. Also, $f(B_1(0))$  and $g(B_1(0))$ are compact and so they attain maximum and minimum on the circle.(Is my reasoning correct?)

Therefore, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $|\epsilon g(z)|<|f(z)|$ on $B_1(0)$. Using Rouché's theorem $f(z)+\epsilon g(z)$ and $f(z)$ have the same number of zero inside the circle, and it remains to show that $f(z)+\epsilon g(z)$ does not vanish on the circle. At this point, I don't know how to show it.
Can anybody give an insight?..

Comment: $|\epsilon g(z)|<|f(z)|$ implies that $f(z)+\epsilon g(z) \ne 0$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1358223/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/651150/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the idea.

let $m$ be the mininum of $|f(z)|$ on the circle $|z| = 1$

let $M$ be the maximum of $|g(z)|$ on the circle.

Since the functions are holomorphic on the disk, these extrema must exist.

Let $\epsilon < \frac {m}{M}$

Then by Roche's theorem as $|f(z)|>|\epsilon g(z)|$ everywhere on the countour, $f(z) + \epsilon g(z)$ has the same number of zeros as $f(z)$ inside the contour.

Comment: My confusion was that Rouche theorem only asserts the same number of zero INSIDE the contour, but not ON the contour,  but reading your post maybe I misunderstand the theorem. When it says inside the contour, it includes the contour also.

Comment: Yes, there is one zero inside the contour.  That is what you have been asked to show.